# JavaScript 1.6 Array.map() and Array.filter() not working with built in functions as arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays

This works fine:

```
["655971", "2343", "343"].map(function(x) { return parseInt(x) }) // [655971, 2343, 343]
```

But this doesnt:

```
["655971", "2343", "343"].map(parseInt) // [655971, NaN, NaN]
```

The same happens for Array.filter()

What am I missing here?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, this situation is described, in detail, on the the [MDN `Array.prototype.map` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Example:_Tricky_use_case) which is referenced by the following blog post:[Allen Wirfs-Brock - A JavaScript Optional Argument Hazard](http://www.wirfs-brock.com/allen/posts/166).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because `map` passes more arguments than just the array item into the callback function. You get:

```
callback(item, index, array)
```

Normally your function would just ignore the arguments it didn't need. But `parseInt` accepts an optional second parameter:

```
parseInt(string, base)
```

for the first call, `base` is the `index` `0`. That works okay because ECMAScript defines that `base=0` is the same as omitting the argument, and consequently allows decimal, octal or hex (using decimal in this case).

For the second and third items, `base` is `1` or `2`. It tries to parse the number as base-1 (which doesn't exist) or base-2 (binary). Since the first number in the string is a digit that doesn't exist in those bases, you get a `NaN`.

In general, `parseInt` without a base is pretty questionable anyway, so you probably want:

```
["655971", "2343", "343"].map(function(x) { return parseInt(x, 10) })
```

Comment: Another option (although with different semantics) in some cases is to use the `Number` function. When called without `new` it converts its argument to a number, similar to the unary `+` operator.

Comment: (Yep... `Number` or `+` are fine, though they wont ensure it's an integer number.)

Comment: `.map(function(x) { return +x; }`. You could possibly also do it with `Number` as simply `.map(Number)`, since the `Number` function doesn't take any extra parameters like `parseInt` does. However that's assuming that ECMAScript will never add any more optional parameters (is this a safe assumption? hmm). Incidentally both `Number` and `+` will accept a hex string (but not, thankfully, accidental octals).

Comment: just a tiny quibble, but although it might not be supported by JavaScript, base-1 does exist.  It's called unarry and for example the number 4 could be written 1111.base-1

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `map` expects that the callback should be a function that accepts three arguments, `callbackfn(value, index, array)`.

The second argument is clashing with the `radix` argument of the [`parseInt(string, radix)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.1.2.2) function.

Map calls parseInt like this for each element:

```
parseInt("655971",0); // 655971
parseInt("2343", 1);  // NaN
parseInt("343", 2);   // NaN
```

The first one works because if radix is undefined or 0, it is assumed to be 10.

Comment: wish I could give both you guys the answer but had to choose the first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Array.Filter takes a function that returns information whether or not the item to evaluated satisfies the condition.  IsNumeric will work for what you want.

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays